# pyinstaller questions and issues

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using python 3.6.8 with Linux ubuntu and I have a py.file (pyinst_tester.py) that I want to test pyinstaller with:
I have three files (pyinst_tester.py) (bell.mp3) (filetotestadd.txt)

The (pyinst_tester.py), plays a bell sound, only after reading a play command from the text file (filetotestadd.txt)

If I use pyinstaller, i can get this to work, however, when (pyins_teseter.py) turns to an EXE....it does not contain (bell.mp3) or (filetotestadd.txt), as removal of either of them from the directory, gives no sound.

as instructed in the pyinstaller manual and it is added to the spec file indeed as expected, but I would have thought that when you make a single file EXE, it contains, (filetotestadd.txt) and (bell.mp3) INSIDE IT thus making these files redundant from the directory they are in and irrelevant to the EXE...thus removable.

AM I missing something ??...and if not, how can i get one EXE file, that has both, the mp3 and the text file INSIDE IT ?

Thank you

What am I not understanding properly.

I tried:
   pyinstaller -F --add-data 'filetotestadd.txt:.' pyinst_tester.py

this is the code I am trying to turn to exe.

```
import subprocess

f=open('testfile1','w')
f.write('This has worked')
f.close()

f=open('testfile1','r')
test=f.readline()
f.close()

print(test)



f=open('filetotestadd.txt','r')
read=f.readline()

if 'play' in read:

    subprocess.call(['cvlc','bell.mp3'])
```

Comment: The .exe file generated by pyinstaller is a self-extracting executable.  When you run it, it extracts the contents to your %TEMP% directory, runs the python files, then when finished it deletes the contents from %TEMP%.  To run it properly, you have to have all of the files you need packaged with the .exe

Comment: ok..you did not read my question...I asked why although i add files to the main program, after i package it , if i remove the files under the assumption that a copy of them has been packaged inside the main.exe, the app does not work....isnt the idea of packaging inside, that the mp3 files are removed and imbeded inside the exe? and therefore not needed outside?

Comment: ah, my mistake.  it likely comes down to how you are referencing the files in your python script.  Are you using relative paths or absolute paths?

Comment: I POSTED MY CODE IN MY MAIN.PY FILE..please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question. I have tried everything and i cannot do it. and i am getting no more feedback. therefore i am going to close it.

pyinstaller -F --add-data doesnt do it.